# Pickadate: Convert date to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, datepicker, unix-timestamp, pickadate

I have read the API located here:
http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/

but couldn't find a way to convert the date output by the picker to a unix timestamp integer. Has anyone had any luck with it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow.  This is a good question, but would be very much improved by providing more information, such as what language you're using (I guess JavaScript?), an example of what you have tried, and adding tags that help people who know the answer find the question.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. Yes, it's javascript. The datepicker is called with 

$('.timepicker').pickatime()

and it outputs a date of a form: 15 April, 2016

From the API reference, I couldn't find a way to output that as a UNIX timestamp so I can do some date range comparisons on the server(using Wordpress). Next solution would be trying doing that on the server through PHP but I was looking for a way I could do it before the value is saved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'set' event

```
picker.on({
  set: function(thingSet) {
    if (thingSet.select) {
      console.log(thingSet.select);
    }
  }
})
```

see the [docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#events-callbacks) 
and see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqMExW)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript Date.parse() method to convert the date string returned by onSet to the Unix epoch time in milliseconds.

```
// date selector
var my_date = $('#my_date').pickadate({
    // onSet fires each time the date is changed
    onSet: function(context) {
        // only proceed if the returned object
        // has the select key
        if(context.select){
            // JavaScript Date.parse() automatically parses 
            // the date string into Unix epoch time in milliseconds
            var unix_timestamp = Date.parse(context.select);
            // log to console
            console.log(unix_timestamp);
        }
    }
});
```